# want to change nav links color on hover when scroll down to top --jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i just want to change the font color on hover when scrollTop() > 10

My CSS

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
 color:#fff;
}
.navbar-default.scrolled{
  background-color: #1F1F1F;
}
```

i wanna make #10d9e4 this links color to be on hover when nav changes it's style

My JS

```
  var a = $(".navbar-default").offset().top;
  $(document).on('scroll', function() {
   if ($(this).scrollTop() > 10) {
    $('.navbar-default').addClass("scrolled");
   } else {
    $('.navbar-default').removeClass("scrolled");
   }
 });
```

Comment: `$('body').bind('scroll',function(){ });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add rule for hover when `.navbar-default` has class 'scrolled', it will redefine default `#fff` color:

```css
.navbar-default.scrolled .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
  color: #10d9e4;
}
```